# Behaviour of withDefaultValue in mutable.Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can anyone explain how a default value in mutable map works?

```
scala> val mmap = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Set[String]]().withDefaultValue{mutable.Set[String]()}
mmap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] = Map()

scala> mmap("a") += "b"
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(b)
```

Map is empty, no keys.

```
scala> mmap
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] = Map()
```

But the key I just tried to edit is showing data.

```
scala> mmap("a")
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(b)
```

Why is `res2` an empty map but `mmap("a")` have a value?

Comment: It looks like you mutated the default value instead of creating a map entry. I'll also guess that this does not work as you might expect, since `mmap("x") == mmap("y")` both return the same (default value) instance

Comment: Ok, I still don't really understand. Mind elaborating?

Comment: It behaves as `(mmap("a")).+=("b")`, not `mmap.assign("a", mmap("a")+"b")`

Comment: Isn't `mmap("a")` a reference to a mutable set? Specifcally why doesn't `(mmap("a")).+=("b")` behave as `mmap.assign("a", mmap("a")+"b")`?

Comment: Don't use mutable collections, and you will never have problems like this (and many, many others)

Comment: @LewisR It changes the mutable set that is the default value of the map. It does not mutate the map itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By modifying key that does not exist in the map you basically changing the default value, not adding a new key.

Let's say you want to add some stuff to set with key `a` in your map.

```
val mmap = 
    mutable.Map[ String, mutable.Set[ String ] ]()
    .withDefaultValue( mutable.Set[ String ]() )

// Changind default value
mmap( "a" ) += "b"
mmap( "a" ) += "c"
```

Now the default value of `mmap` has 2 elements but still no keys. Now you 'change' the other nonexisting key:

```
// Still changind default value
mmap( "c" ) += "c1"
```

In reality you are still changing the default value

```
// Printing default value
println( mmap("a") )
// Result => Set(c, c1, b)
```

In order to create a real key use assignment

```
// Creating a new key
mmap("b") = mutable.Set[ String ]( "b1", "b2" )

mmap.foreach( println )
// Result => (b,Set(b1, b2))
```