# folding with mutable.Map and mutable.Set does not work when using Set.add

Tags: scala

I'm just wondering why my grouping of values does not work in the code  below. Technically, the Map and Set are both mutable so my add(intValue) should change the set (and indirectly the aggregator map).

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

val original = Iterator[(String, Int)](
  "one" -> 1,
  "two" -> 20,
  "three" -> 30,
  "one" -> 11
)

val folded = original.foldLeft(
  Map[String, Set[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Set.empty))
{
  case (agg, (strVal, intVal)) =>
    //agg += ((strVal, agg(strVal) + intVal))  <-- option 1  works
    agg(strVal).add(intVal)  // <--- option 2 does not work
    agg                      // <--- option 2 does not work   
}
```

For option 1, the result is as expected ( a grouping of "one" -> Set(1, 11) ...) 
For option 2 I get an empty Map.

Comment: BTW, I'm using scala 2.11.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.withDefaultValue` does not *add* the value to `Map`. 
Use `.getOrElseUpdate(strVal, Set.empty).add(intVal)` instead.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not add the value to Map"  ?  I'm using .withDefaultValue to start the folding with an empty Map which returns and empty Set when the key does not exists.  What's wrong with my approach ?

Comment: The problem is the mutability of the Set in the 
withDefaultValue(mutable.Set.empty)

The map returns this Set every time it does not find the value for a particular key so actually the same set accumulates values. 

There's another SO discussion for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650121/behaviour-of-withdefaultvalue-in-mutable-map

Comment: I was under the impression that get(missingKey) creates an entry (missingKey, defaultValue) in the map.  My assumption was incorrect. It seems I need to put somehow a value so that my map is updated properly.

Answer (score 1):

when you call get(key) on this map with a default value it never adds the key that you passed, from the looks of it, it adds another key something on the lines of a "null key" within the map for all default values, that's why you get the same Set each time you do a get, but its not the value you are looking for.

Comment: so what exactly did I miss ? ... is there any scaladoc or any type of documentation that I missed ?

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but as a general rule if an API changes the map, it would be specifically mentioned so. as for the requirement, you did have a list to start with i'd recommend doing

`original.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)` to achieve the same 

result.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a list but an Iterator and I don't want to keep all my data in memory ( List). But anyway I found the problem ... check my comments in the accepted answer.